# Convert rows into columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, join

I want to Convert rows to columns (week days name), but I only have one entry per row and the rest of columns are empty (for teacher and time slot).

Table structure:

[image: table structure]

the output of follow query:

[image: query result]

and my query is:

```
 SELECT
 /* Employee section */
 CONCAT(emp.first_name, " ",emp.middle_name,"", emp.last_name) as     employeeFullName,

/* Timetable Entry section */
CONCAT(ct.start_time," - ",ct.end_time) as Slots,

if(wd.name='Monday',CONCAT(sb.name," - ",bt.name),null) Monday,
if(wd.name='Tuesday',CONCAT(sb.name," - ",bt.name),null) Tuesday,
if(wd.name='Wednesday',CONCAT(sb.name," - ",bt.name),null) Wednesday,
if(wd.name='Thurseday',CONCAT(sb.name," - ",bt.name),null) Thurseday,
if(wd.name='Friday',CONCAT(sb.name," - ",bt.name),null) Friday,
if(wd.name='Saturday',CONCAT(sb.name," - ",bt.name),null) Saturday,
if(wd.name='Sunday',CONCAT(sb.name," - ",bt.name),null) Sunday 

FROM `timetable_entries` te 

left Join `weekdays` wd ON te.weekday_id=wd.id
left Join `employees` emp  ON te.employee_id=emp.id
left Join `class_timings` ct  ON te.class_timing_id=ct.id
left Join `batches` bt  ON te.batch_id=bt.id
left Join `subject` sb  ON te.subject_id=sb.id

WHERE te.employee_id is not null
Group By  te.class_timing_id,te.employee_id
```

Comment: I'm pretty shure "transforming rows into columns" is not what you want. This contradicts the principle of a relational database.

Comment: thanks for reply, sorry for confusion ,but i think the problem is clear from images and query!

Comment: I haven't got time to elaborate fully but I think you need to start your query from class timings and pull out every class starting at 08:00, 09:00, etc. From there you can get the details of the class, the week day, employees, etc.

Comment: @d3v_1 thanks, you make a valied point but at the same time other teachers may have classes (subject) on the same day, so for a teacher only one timeslot

Comment: Have you tried playing around with the GROUP BY clause? You may find you are stopping the query from returning more than one class per time slot. It's a bit difficult to help without seeing the other tables and data.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should change the whole thinking. Try something like this:

```
     SELECT
     /* Employee section */
     CONCAT(emp.first_name, " ",emp.middle_name,"", emp.last_name) as     employeeFullName,

    /* Timetable Entry section */
    CONCAT(ct.start_time," - ",ct.end_time) as Slots,
wd.name as weekDayName,
CONCAT(sb.name," - ",bt.name) as name
```

Now you can access each day as "weekDayName" and have "name" as concat. I think it's easier becouse you dont have columns that you actualy don't need and this don't check "if" for each row.

Comment: thanks for reply  but i m not showing the weekDayName but anything related to teacher at given slot, I m creating a timetable for teachers, I put the weekdays as columns because it is fixed and rest of stuff is changing, So Please can u help me to write a query for timetable, and related tables are mentioned in structure table as foreign keys, thanks